# zsh: command not found: R on terminal using Big Sur Mac

Tags: r, macos, terminal, rscript

I installed R from official cran website and i can run R from the Rstudio but when i try to use R from the terminal, I get the following results:

```
(base) ege@Eges-MBP ~ % R  
zsh: command not found: R
(base) ege@Eges-MBP ~ % RScript 
zsh: command not found: RScript
```

How can i enable the command R and run RScript from terminal on my mac?

Comment: try opening R from the terminal within Rstudio (usually next to the R Console tab). if it works, type `which R` in also in the terminal within Rstudio *OR* look at the path that RStudio is using to find R under `Tools` > `Global Options` > `R version` right on top of the options window. Then you may either that path to your $PATH, or create a (symbolic) link from R binary to the folder where your binaries usually are. (maybe /usr/local/bin, I am not sure how it is in MacOS

Comment: can u use R terminals other than `zsh`?

Comment: Hi, i just switched to Mac from Windows so I am new to MacOS. I have typed `which R` to the terminal in Rstudio , it did not throw an error but i got nothing returned. Instead, i have used `R.home()` from terminal and it returned `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources`

Comment: great that you found a solution. Just to be a little clear, the `terminal` and `R console` in general and in RStudio are two different things.  In RStudio, next to usual `Console` where you can interact your R enviroment, there is also a `Terminal` (and some other tabs, such as `Jobs´). This Terminal tab can be used just like a normal Terminal. It is a bit confusing, but you entered R.home() in the Console, not in the terminal. (it sounds pedantic, but the right terminology helps a lot finding the right questions and answers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

I first found the location of R and Rscript on my disk by running `R.home()` on my R console.
Then, i followed [this](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/) guide and copied the returned location from `R.home()` and pasted on a new line on `/etc/paths`.

Then, i restarted the terminal and i was able to use `R` and `Rscript` commands

Answer (score 9):

This is possibly due to a bug with the current version of CRAN's R installation package (present as of version 4.0.5), that affects certain versions of Big Sur. I've answered this question here: [R: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67324807/r-command-not-found/67452876)

In short, if running `uname -r` gives you a release number greater than 20, then you may need to manually create symbolic links that the package installer failed to.

In short:

```
    sudo -s
    mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
    cd /usr/local/bin
    rm -f R Rscript
    ln -s /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R .
    ln -s /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript .
```

Comment: Thanks Yuri! I installed R from R Cran and the first and 3rd step weren't needed for some reason. But the last two steps worked in `sudo`

Comment: Worked for me after restarting zsh

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. I was able to solve it by adding the below line (path obtained by running `R.home()` inside R) to my `.zshrc`. Thanks for the guidance.

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources:${PATH}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the directory where the R binaries are installed to the `PATH` environment variable.

You can add this in the current session as follows:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH
```

To have this done automatically in every new session ensure that this line is added to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/:${PATH}"
```